# I'm trying to go up and down the DOM in Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
full_text = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("the-full-text")

for _ in full_text:
    if "word" in _:
        full_answer = _.find_element_by_xpath('..')     
        _.find_element_by_xpath("..//div[@class='some-text']").click()
```

I get this error:

> if "word" in _: TypeError: argument of type 'WebElement' is not iterable

I know it's possible to use `driver.execute_script(""" javascript here """)` but somehow I don't think that should be the first resort.

So I'm just trying to take one element in a list, move up the DOM from there, and select a different element inside of there. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: It makes sense but seems quite vague. Can you show us some text that you are attempting to process as well as actual code. Then tell us the specifics of the difficulties you encounter and ask a definite question.

Comment: Can you give your full traceback and `xml` which you try to parse ?

Comment: Show `HTML` code sample and desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line `if "word" in _:` you are trying to check if `WebElement` has the string "word" in it. `WebElement` is a single object, therefor not iterable as the error message says, that looks something like

```
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="dae57d0d-9570-4693-bb7f-8aa31ab24699", element="49e4afcd-f6c3-4b62-bba0-a3b21e08c78d")>
```

If you want to check the text of the element you need to use the `text` property

```
if "word" in _.text:
```